# Why trap didn't work in a pipeline

Tags: linux, bash, shell, bash-trap

In this script
We have a script trap.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
trap "echo trapped" EXIT
exit 0
```

and test.sh. If test.sh is like

```
#!/bin/bash
. trap.sh
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
./trap.sh | :
```

trap works

But if test.sh is like

```
#!/bin/bash
. trap.sh | :
```

the trap didn't work.

Anybody know why is this?

Comment: Is any script ever run such that the working directory (cwd) is not where the scripts are?

Comment: @wallyk No, it's not at where the script is.

Answer (score 1):

Better change your test command to `. trap.sh|cat` (standard output from `trap.sh` couldn't be displayed with `:`). But even then there is no output, so you are right: the trap didn't work. This must be a bug in bash, and should be reported to the maintainers.

Interestingly, when we `echo $$` from inside the script trap.sh, we see that it is executed by the same shell that executes the whole pipeline `. trap.sh|cat`, contradictory to the manual's statement: *Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e.,  in a subshell).* **This was a fallacy, see comments.** Perhaps this is related to some optimization to minimize subshell creation, but that's just speculation.

Comment: `$$` always evaluates to the process ID of the parent shell, even if the child executes in a different process.

Comment: +1, as I think I agree this might be a bug. I replaced the echo with `touch trap.fired`, to make sure this wasn't an issue with standard output just being lost somewhere. With `. trap.sh | :`, the file was not created.

Comment: Although the bash manual states: _$      Expands  to  the  process ID of the shell_, you are evidently right that `$$` in this case evaluates to the process ID of the parent shell. Thanks to your comment, I discovered the shell variable *BASHPID*, about which the manual says: _Expands to the process id of the  current  bash  process.   This differs  from  $$ under certain circumstances, such as subshells that do not require bash to be re-initialized._ Indeed, `echo $BASHPID` shows different values.

Answer (score 1):

I modified `trap.sh` to include the `xtrace` option.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
trap 'echo trapped' EXIT
exit 0
```

Running `trap.sh` as a script produces

~ $ ./trap.sh | cat
    + trap 'echo trapped' EXIT
    + exit 0
    + echo trapped
    trapped

Sourcing it first, however produces

```
~ $ . trap.sh | cat
++ trap 'echo trapped' EXIT
++ exit 0
```

This indicates that the `trap` is executed in a deeper subshell (why, I don't know), and that the trap itself is never executed (I confirmed in a second experiment by `touch`ing a file int he trap instead of just echoing, in case there was an issue with standard output being inherited; the file was never touched).

My guess is that somehow the `EXIT` signal is being ignored prior to the `source` command being executed, based on this sentence from the description of the `trap` command in the man page:

> Signals ignored upon
>                 entry to the shell cannot be trapped or reset.

As a result, the `trap` command is executed, but the trap itself is never registered, and so does not fire.

Answer (score 0):

The command on the left hand side of a pipe is run in a subshell:

```
exit | grep
```

The exit sigtrap seems not to be propagated to subshells.

```
trap 'echo T >&2' EXIT ; (exit)    # Nothing.
```

Comment: I noticed the subshell problem. But when we call . trap.sh | :, what I think is we call trap.sh in a subshell, and the subshell called trap, when the subshell exits, trap call should be invoked like we call ./trap.sh | :. I didn't see why there are different outcomes.